# Chrome extension manage background state across multiple browser instances

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to manage background state across multiple "People" browser instances?

For example, I have two chrome windows open and logged in as different users with the extension installed on both of the windows. Can I keep a shared background state so person 1 can communicate with person 2?

Comment: From your extension's view point that's basically two different computers so you'll have to use a shared remote server endpoint. AFAIK the only local alternative is to use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging).

Comment: @wOxxOm Or a _local_ server endpoint. But still an external program in addition to the extension.